# Looking for a way to read out Battery and PowerAdapter Information via ioreg

Tags: macos, battery, energy

I'm trying to collect information on power usage of our Apple (for now macOS only) devices. I came across some good posts and was already able to read out the `AppleSmartBattery` object via `ioreg`. That already would help me to determine if it is a laptop or a desktop model. But is is actually pretty hard to get more detailed information around the actual power drain. I'm less interested if a device runs on battery but actually more on the consumption if it is connected to a charger. I found the child object of `PowerTelemetryData` which contains a lot of interesting information but have no real clue how to interpret the data (reformatted for better readability).

```
$ /usr/sbin/ioreg -rc AppleSmartBattery | grep PowerTelemetryData
      "PowerTelemetryData" = {
         "WallEnergyEstimate"=2305,
         "AccumulatedSystemPowerIn"=28547763,
         "AdapterEfficiencyLossAccum ulatorCount"=3586,
         "AccumulatedWallEnergyEstimate"=9196925,
         "SystemInputVoltage"=12145,
         "SystemPowerInAccumulatorCount"=3586,
         "SystemEnergyConsumed"=1987,
         "SystemPowerIn"=7156,
         "SystemLoad"=7576,
         "PowerTelemetryErrorCount"=0,
         "AccumulatedSystemLoad"=28544320,
         "SystemLoadAccumulatorCount"=3587,
         "AccumulatedSystemEnergyConsumed"=7928273,
         "AdapterEfficiencyLoss"=318,
         "SystemInputCurrent"=588,
         "AccumulatedAdapterEfficiencyLoss"=1268652
   }
```

From what I can see there is already some items which are pretty interesting, e.g. `WallEnergyEstimate`, `AccumulatedWallEnergyEstimate` or `SystemEnergyConsumed`. But have no clue in what unit of measure these read outs actually are and couldn't find any (even non-official) documentation. Is there anyone that can help?

Comment: Validating with a friend I figured out that this object is only available on Ventura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And playing around with all the data it seems that it is pretty self-explanatory. For almost all values you might assume the prefix of *milli* – so  *millivolt*, *milliampere*, *milliwatt*.

- `SystemInputCurrent` is the currently measured current in *milliampere*
- `SystemInputVoltage` is the currently measured voltage in *millivolt*
- If you multiply those and divide by 1000 (to eliminate one *milli*) you get  roughly the value of `SystemPowerIn` measured in *milliwatt*

And actually one of the most interesting fields is `AccumulatedSystemEnergyConsumed` which gives you the total amount of energy consumed measured in *Joules*. So actually dividing this by 3,600,000 will give you the amount of *kWh* your machine consumed since ??? (I guess it is ever).

Found the answer – so closing this question. But will need to look for a different approach that also works on older macOS versions.